# How can I clear my react form when it is submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, state

I have made two react components `Form` and `Input`. How can I make the `Input` components inside `Form` blank when the form is submitted? Another question: do you think that the `Input` component inside the form is unnecessary because my project has only one form?

// Input.js

```
export const Input = ({ id, className, onKeyUp, value }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        id={id}
        className=""
        onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
        value={value}
      />
    </>
  );
};

// Form.js

export const Form = ({ addData }) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    weight: "",
    height: "",
    bmi: null,
    date: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0],
  });

  const initialState = {
    weight: "",
    height: "",
    bmi: null,
    date: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0],
  }

  function sendDataToApp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const heightSquared = Math.pow(userData.height / 100, 2);
    const calculateBMI = userData.weight / heightSquared;
    userData.bmi = calculateBMI;
    addData(userData);
    setUserData({...initialState});

  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      <form
        className=""
        onSubmit={sendDataToApp}
      >
        <Inputlabel
          htmlFor="weight"
          className=""
        />
        <Input
          className=""
          id="weight"
          onKeyUp={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, weight: e.target.value })}
          value={userData.weight}
        />
        <Inputlabel
          htmlFor="height"
          className=""
        />
        <Input
          className=""
          id="height"
          onKeyUp={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, height: e.target.value })}
          value={userData.height}
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="submit"
          className=""
          disabled={userData.weight === null || userData.height === null}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

// App.js

export const App = () => {
  const [bmi, setBmi] = useState([]);

  function bmiToHook(newBmi) {
    setBmi([...bmi, newBmi]);
    console.log(bmi);
  }
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Title />
      <Form addData={bmiToHook} />
      <Chart dataToChart={bmi}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening, but, to begin with:
setUserData expects one argument, not two. Could that be the case?
+ You'd better use onChange rather then onKeyUp event.

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms have a [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method built into them that you can take advantage of. You can access the `<form>` element with [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```
export const Form = ({ addData }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  ...

  function sendDataToApp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ref.current.reset() // <-- add this line. 
    // You probably want to add it after validation though
    ...
  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      <form
        className=""
        onSubmit={sendDataToApp}
        ref={ref}
      >
      ...
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```